# Polarization selection rules

Tags: semiconductor-physics

So, I am just reviewing some of my physics stuff, and I have read something about polarization selection rules in inter-band-transitions in quantum wells.

If I calculate them, I get a strength of 1/2 for heavy holes-transitions (HH) in x- and y-directions, and a strength of 1/6 for light holes-transitions (LH). My problem is now: What does this mean? Do the HH-transitions happen three times more than the LH-transitions, or are they the probability of each transition?

But if they are the probability, they have to add up to 1, but they don't. So, where is my mistake?

Comment: What's the system here?  What is an "HH transition" and a "LH transition"?  What are the states involved?

Comment: Fixed, but maybe I still forgot something.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you're missing degeneracy of the bands? Meaning if you assume a 3 fold degenerate LH band, you would end up with a strength of 3/6, so your probabilities would add up to 1.

(Intended as a comment, but I can't comment yet. Maybe some moderator can transform this answer into a comment?)